# By using JQuery, how to play the video when the mouse enter once and pause the video when the mouse enter twice?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video, mouseover

I want to achieve the effect that when the user's mouse enters into the video frame, it will trigger the movie. Also, when the user's mouse leaves the video, it will still continue to play.

However, when the user's mouse enters into the video frame again, the video will be paused. Is there any way to achieve this? I am new to this field.

---

Here is what I have so far
:

**JQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#video1').mouseover(
        function()
            {
                $(this).get(0).play();
            }
        );
    });
```

**HTML:**

```
<video id = "video1" width = "420">
    <source src = "lololol.mp4" type = "video/mp4">
</video>
```

Answer (score 4):

Just check the state of the video. And use the mouseenter event instead.

```
$('#video1').mouseenter(
   function()
   {
      if($(this).get(0).paused)
          $(this).get(0).play();
      else
          $(this).get(0).pause();
   }
);
```

Comment: Yeah, this is better.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want to create a variable, increment it on mouseenter, and check its value for even or odd:

```
var movieHoverCt = 0;

$('#video1').mouseenter(function () {
    if (movieHoverCt % 2 === 0) { // even
        $(this).get(0).play();
    } else { // odd
        $(this).get(0).stop();
    }
    movieHoverCt++;
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I have made it! But do you know how it can works for multiple videos?